Get initial content in Custom View
In FullCalendar, in dayGridWeek, is there any way to put an additional column after the 7 columns/days?
I checked the documentation, it seems that it's possible to do this with the Custom View via js.
Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/charitysmith/pen/JjpRvmd
const CustomViewConfig = {

    classNames: [ 'custom-view' ],

    content: function(props) {
      let segs = sliceEvents(props, true); // allDay=true
      let html =
        '<div class="view-title">' +
          props.dateProfile.currentRange.start.toUTCString() +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="view-events">' +
          segs.length + ' events:' +
          '<ul>' +
            segs.map(function(seg) {
              return seg.def.title + ' (' + seg.range.start.toUTCString() + ')'
            }).join('') +
          '</ul>' +
        '</div>'

      return { html: html }
    }

  }

But with this way, content() totally replaces the initial view of the calendar.
So, is there any way to get the initial content in content(), in order for me to just add the additional column to the initial content?
